# how to merge two dataframes on both indexes and columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Here's the problem: I know how to merge two `DataFrame`s on indexes or on columns, but I am not able to merge them on a both indexes and columns.

I have two `DataFrame`s and I want to merge them on indexes (which are dates) and on column `id`. I created some sample data to better explain my problem.

```
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(200)
dates = [date(2020, 1, 31), date(2020, 2, 28)]
a = {"id": ["A", "B"] * len(dates), "w": [.5, .5] * len(dates)}
b = {"id": ["B", "A"] * len(dates), "x": np.random.random(2 * len(dates))}

a = pd.DataFrame(a, index=dates * len(dates))
b = pd.DataFrame(b, index=dates * len(dates))
```

Desired output:

```
           id    w         x
2020-01-31  A  0.5  0.226547
2020-02-28  B  0.5  0.947632
2020-01-31  A  0.5  0.428309
2020-02-28  B  0.5  0.594420
```

Please note that I am searching for a general solution, where `a` and `b` do not necessarily contains the same indexes or elements in `id`.

Comment: your example is a bit ambiguous, should the id column be more ['A','B','B','A]? to actually have an interest to merge on the index and the column id

Comment: you're right, I'm gonna edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `set_index` to append the columns, use `join` and then `reset_index` like

```
print(a.set_index('id', append=True)\
       .join(b.set_index('id', append=True), how='outer')\
       .reset_index('id'))
           id    w         x
2020-01-31  A  0.5  0.947632
2020-02-28  B  0.5  0.226547
2020-01-31  B  0.5  0.594420
2020-02-28  A  0.5  0.428309
```

or the opposite direction with `merge`:

```
print(a.reset_index()\
       .merge(b.reset_index(), on=['index', 'id'], how='outer')\
       .set_index('index'))
           id    w         x
index                       
2020-01-31  A  0.5  0.947632
2020-02-28  B  0.5  0.226547
2020-01-31  B  0.5  0.594420
2020-02-28  A  0.5  0.428309
```

Just to be sure that is what you want to do, let's assume a and b are like this with another id:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["A", "B", 'B','A'] , "w": np.random.random(4)}, 
                 index=[date(2020, 1, 31), date(2020, 2, 28)]*2)
#           id         w
#2020-01-31  A  0.764141
#2020-02-28  B  0.002861
#2020-01-31  B  0.357424
#2020-02-28  A  0.909695

b = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["A", "B", 'C','A'], "x": np.random.random(4)}, 
                 index=[date(2020, 1, 31), date(2020, 2, 28)]*2)
#           id         x
#2020-01-31  A  0.456081
#2020-02-28  B  0.981803
#2020-01-31  C  0.867357
#2020-02-28  A  0.986028
```

Then the result of the method with `join` is:

```
           id         w         x
2020-01-31  A  0.764141  0.456081
2020-01-31  B  0.357424       NaN
2020-01-31  C       NaN  0.867357
2020-02-28  A  0.909695  0.986028
2020-02-28  B  0.002861  0.981803
```

Comment: thanks, I hoped for a some hidden `pd.merge` arg, but this works!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a new column using `b['w'] = a['w']`. This is note really a merge, but a copy from a into b.

The full code is :

```
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(200)
ids = ["A", "B"]
dates = [date(2020, 1, 31), date(2020, 2, 28)]
a = {"id": ids * len(dates), "w": [.5, .5] * len(dates)}
b = {"id": ids * len(dates), "x": np.random.random(len(ids) * len(dates))}

a = pd.DataFrame(a, index=dates * len(dates))
b = pd.DataFrame(b, index=dates * len(dates))

b['w'] = a['w']
print(b)
```

EDIT:
Other way to obtain the result you want (well, I'm not so sure because of the duplicate 'id' column). Please let me known the structure of the id of the two dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd

a = pandas.DataFrame([
    ['A', 0.5],
    ['B', 1],
    ['C', 1.5],
    ['D', 2.]],
    columns=['id', 'w'], 
    index=['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'])
print(a)

b = pandas.DataFrame([
    ['A', 0.5],
    ['B', 1],
    ['C', 1.5],
    ['D', 2.]],
    columns=['id', 'x'], 
    index=['2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'])
print(b)

c = pandas.concat([a, b], axis=1)
print(c)
```

output:

```
           id    w
2020-01-01  A  0.5
2020-01-02  B  1.0
2020-01-03  C  1.5
2020-01-04  D  2.0
           id    x
2020-01-02  A  0.5
2020-01-03  B  1.0
2020-01-04  C  1.5
2020-01-05  D  2.0
             id    w   id    x
2020-01-01    A  0.5  NaN  NaN
2020-01-02    B  1.0    A  0.5
2020-01-03    C  1.5    B  1.0
2020-01-04    D  2.0    C  1.5
2020-01-05  NaN  NaN    D  2.0
```

Comment: thanks, but the example was simplified. I need a general approach where `a` and `b` does contains different indexes or ids

Comment: I've edited my post to provide a more general solution. The structure of the two dataframe is a key to give you the answer you want

Comment: @Oliver thanks again, but the results are not aligned, and there shouldn't be `NaN` given that data

Comment: The pandas.concat function used here concatenate based on the index (here: day series). Note that the df 'a' index is not the same as 'b'.  The concat function won't give you ```Nan``` values if the indexes are exactly the same.

Comment: I didn't see it, sorry. but the problem remains: I want to merge also on `id`

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper column based on cumcount, as give indexes a name to make it eaiser to merge on indexes:

```
a['helper'] = a.groupby([a.index, 'id']).cumcount()
b['helper'] = b.groupby([b.index, 'id']).cumcount()
a = a.rename_axis('date')
b = b.rename_axis('date')

a.merge(b, on=['date','id','helper']).drop('helper', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
           id    w         x
date                        
2020-01-31  A  0.5  0.947632
2020-02-28  B  0.5  0.226547
2020-01-31  A  0.5  0.594420
2020-02-28  B  0.5  0.428309
```

Comment: thanks, but this solution does not seems to generalize well. it won't work if:
`ids = ["A", "B"]`
`dates = [date(2020, 1, 31), date(2020, 2, 28)]`
`a = {"id": ids * len(dates), "w": [.5, .5] * len(dates)}`
`ids.append("C")`
`b = {"id": ids * len(dates), "x": np.random.random(len(ids) * len(dates))}`
`a = pd.DataFrame(a, index=dates * (len(ids) - 1))`
`b = pd.DataFrame(b, index=dates * len(ids))`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a merger issue but more feeding to me.
Adding seems to work

```
a['x'] = b['x']
```

Comment: thanks, but the example was simplified. I need a general approach where a and b does contains different indexes or ids